# Upload two files using PHP

Tags: php, upload

I know this may sound relatively basic question, but still wanted to ask. I need to upload two files at once by creating two file input in my form one for each file. Until now I have used a basic script for testing to upload a single file.

I also found some examples how to upload muliple files, but in my case I am having two upload fields and I want the user to upload the two files. Once uploaded I wanted to save it onmy webserver. Any simple example would be of good help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply just a case of changing the variable names and doing everything twice.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="filea" />
<input type="file" name="fileb" />
```

PHP:

```
$filea = $_FILES['filea'];
$fileb = $_FILES['fileb'];
move_uploaded_file($filea['tmp_name'], '/path/to/your/destination/'.$filea['name']);
```

Can you carry on from there?

Comment: Hi Grim, thanks man for the quick answer, I was trying it with using arrays, you saved my day.

Comment: Hi Grim, just a follow up, I can sucessfully upload .txt, .odt, excel files and so, but when I try to upload .pdf files even if it is of small size like 60KB, it is not uploading. Any idea

Comment: You'll have to post your code, as there's no reason for that to be the case. You should probably make it a new question, too.

Answer (score 0):

Extrac data from $_FILES array

`$file_1 = $_FILES['file1']['name']; $file_2 = $_FILES['file2']['name']; move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'], 'pathproc/'.$file_1); move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file2']['tmp_name'], 'pathproc/'.$file_2);`

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is always better to have an explanations in your answers, even a little one.