# How to combine both pdf file and image file upload using php into MySQL?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

I'm a new php learner and currently I'm trying to develop a job portal system. Everything else is running smoothly but I encounter problems when I need to prepare the php for uploading resume and image into the database. I have both the source code to upload image and pdf file separately but I don't know what to do if I have to combine them. Can anyone give me ideas of combining the php source code for both image and pdf file?

**edit:** I have a form where users need to upload their picture and attach their resume, hence the reason why I need to combine both of my resume and image source code below.

image.php

```html
<?php

//To Handle Session Variables on This Page
session_start();

//Including Database Connection From db.php file to avoid rewriting in all files
require_once("db.php");

//If user clicked register button
if(isset($_POST)) {

 //Escape Special Characters In String First
 $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
 $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);

 //Encrypt Password
 $password = base64_encode(strrev(md5($password)));

 //sql query to check if email already exists or not
 $sql = "SELECT email FROM user WHERE email='$email'";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);

 //if email not found then we can insert new data
 if($result->num_rows == 0) {

   //This variable is used to catch errors doing upload process. False means there is some error and we need to notify that user.
  $uploadOk = true;

  //Folder where you want to save your image. THIS FOLDER MUST BE CREATED BEFORE TRYING
  $folder_dir = "uploads/logo/";

  //Getting Basename of file. So if your file location is Documents/New Folder/myResume.pdf then base name will return myResume.pdf
  $base = basename($_FILES['image']['name']); 

  //This will get us extension of your file. So myimage.pdf will return pdf. If it was image.doc then this will return doc.
  $imageFileType = pathinfo($base, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 

  //Setting a random non repeatable file name. Uniqid will create a unique name based on current timestamp. We are using this because no two files can be of same name as it will overwrite.
  $file = uniqid() . "." . $imageFileType; 
   
  //This is where your files will be saved so in this case it will be uploads/image/newfilename
  $filename = $folder_dir .$file;  

  //We check if file is saved to our temp location or not.
  if(file_exists($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) { 

   //Next we need to check if file type is of our allowed extention or not. I have only allowed pdf. You can allow doc, jpg etc. 
   if($imageFileType == "jpg" || $imageFileType == "png")  {

    //Next we need to check file size with our limit size. I have set the limit size to 5MB. Note if you set higher than 2MB then you must change your php.ini configuration and change upload_max_filesize and restart your server
    if($_FILES['image']['size'] < 500000) { // File size is less than 5MB

     //If all above condition are met then copy file from server temp location to uploads folder.
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $filename);

    } else {
     //Size Error
     $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Wrong Size. Max Size Allowed : 5MB";
     $uploadOk = false;
    }
   } else {
    //Format Error
    $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Wrong Format. Only jpg & png Allowed";
    $uploadOk = false;
   }
  } else {
    //File not copied to temp location error.
    $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Something Went Wrong. File Not Uploaded. Try Again.";
    $uploadOk = false;
   }

  //If there is any error then redirect back.
  if($uploadOk == false) {
   header("Location: candidateform.php");
   exit();
  }

  //sql new registration insert query
  $sql = "INSERT INTO user(email, password,logo) VALUES ('$email', '$password', '$file')";

  if($conn->query($sql)===TRUE) {

   //If data inserted successfully then Set some session variables for easy reference and redirect to company login
   $_SESSION['registerCompleted'] = true;
   header("Location: login.php");
   exit();

  } else {
   //If data failed to insert then show that error. Note: This condition should not come unless we as a developer make mistake or someone tries to hack their way in and mess up :D
   echo "Error " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }
 } else {
  //if email found in database then show email already exists error.
  $_SESSION['registerError'] = true;
  header("Location: candidateform.php");
  exit();
 }

 //Close database connection. Not compulsory but good practice.
 $conn->close();

} else {
 //redirect them back to register page if they didn't click register button
 header("Location: candidateform.php");
 exit();
}
```

and here is the resume.php

resume.php

```html
<?php

//To Handle Session Variables on This Page
session_start();

//Including Database Connection From db.php file to avoid rewriting in all files
require_once("db.php");

//If user Actually clicked register button
if(isset($_POST)) {

 //Escape Special Characters In String First
 $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
 $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
 //Encrypt Password
 $password = base64_encode(strrev(md5($password)));

 //sql query to check if email already exists or not
 $sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);

 //if email not found then we can insert new data
 if($result->num_rows == 0) {

   //This variable is used to catch errors doing upload process. False means there is some error and we need to notify that user.
 $uploadOk = true;

 //Folder where you want to save your resume. THIS FOLDER MUST BE CREATED BEFORE TRYING
 $folder_dir = "uploads/resume/";

 //Getting Basename of file. So if your file location is Documents/New Folder/myResume.pdf then base name will return myResume.pdf
 $base = basename($_FILES['resume']['name']); 

 //This will get us extension of your file. So myResume.pdf will return pdf. If it was resume.doc then this will return doc.
 $resumeFileType = pathinfo($base, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 

 //Setting a random non repeatable file name. Uniqid will create a unique name based on current timestamp. We are using this because no two files can be of same name as it will overwrite.
 $file = uniqid() . "." . $resumeFileType;   

 //This is where your files will be saved so in this case it will be uploads/resume/newfilename
 $filename = $folder_dir .$file;  

 //We check if file is saved to our temp location or not.
 if(file_exists($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'])) { 

  //Next we need to check if file type is of our allowed extention or not. I have only allowed pdf. You can allow doc, jpg etc. 
  if($resumeFileType == "pdf")  {

   //Next we need to check file size with our limit size. I have set the limit size to 5MB. Note if you set higher than 2MB then you must change your php.ini configuration and change upload_max_filesize and restart your server
   if($_FILES['resume']['size'] < 500000) { // File size is less than 5MB

    //If all above condition are met then copy file from server temp location to uploads folder.
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"], $filename);

   } else {
    //Size Error
    $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Wrong Size. Max Size Allowed : 5MB";
    $uploadOk = false;
   }
  } else {
   //Format Error
   $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Wrong Format. Only PDF Allowed";
   $uploadOk = false;
  }
 } else {
   //File not copied to temp location error.
   $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Something Went Wrong. File Not Uploaded. Try Again.";
   $uploadOk = false;
  }

 //If there is any error then redirect back.
 if($uploadOk == false) {
  header("Location: register-candidates.php");
  exit();
 }

  $hash = md5(uniqid());


  //sql new registration insert query
  $sql = "INSERT INTO users(email, password,resume, hash) VALUES ('$email', '$password','$file', '$hash')";

  if($conn->query($sql)===TRUE) {
   // Send Email

   // $to = $email;

   // $subject = "Job Portal - Confirm Your Email Address";

   // $message = '
   
   // <html>
   // <head>
   //  <title>Confirm Your Email</title>
   // <body>
   //  <p>Click Link To Confirm</p>
   //  <a href="yourdomain.com/verify.php?token='.$hash.'&email='.$email.'">Verify Email</a>
   // </body>
   // </html>
   // ';

   // $headers[] = 'MIME-VERSION: 1.0';
   // $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
   // $headers[] = 'To: '.$to;
   // $headers[] = 'From: hello@yourdomain.com';
   // //you add more headers like Cc, Bcc;

   // $result = mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers)); // \r\n will return new line. 

   // if($result === TRUE) {

   //  //If data inserted successfully then Set some session variables for easy reference and redirect to login
   //  $_SESSION['registerCompleted'] = true;
   //  header("Location: login.php");
   //  exit();

   // }

   // //If data inserted successfully then Set some session variables for easy reference and redirect to login
   $_SESSION['registerCompleted'] = true;
   header("Location: login.php");
   exit();
  } else {
   //If data failed to insert then show that error. Note: This condition should not come unless we as a developer make mistake or someone tries to hack their way in and mess up :D
   echo "Error " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }
 } else {
  //if email found in database then show email already exists error.
  $_SESSION['registerError'] = true;
  header("Location: candidateform.php");
  exit();
 }

 //Close database connection. Not compulsory but good practice.
 $conn->close();

} else {
 //redirect them back to register page if they didn't click register button
 header("Location: candidateform.php");
 exit();
}
```

Thank you very much for every guidance, suggestions and helps in advance

Comment: What do you mean by 'combining' them? Are you referring to embedding the image in the PDF?

Comment: No. I have a page of registration form that need user to upload their picture and attach their resume. I try combining my source code together but I got numerous errors in return.

Comment: Unrelated, but important: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: thank you for the heads up...but for now I just want to merge them together and think of the attack later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question it appears that you want to upload multiple files (one PDF and one image) in a form and send it to PHP. There are multiple guides written on this:

[Upload two files using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291061/upload-two-files-using-php)

Or for more verbosity, check:

http://findnerd.com/list/view/How-to-upload-two-separate-files-in-php/3268/

If you want to add multiple files to the same upload button, then check:

https://daveismyname.blog/upload-multiple-files-with-a-single-input-with-html-5-and-php

In terms of your code, you will need to do something like:

```
<input type="file" name="resume" />
<input type="file" name="image" />
```

Then in your PHP, you will need to do something like:

```
<?php

//To Handle Session Variables on This Page
session_start();

//Including Database Connection From db.php file to avoid rewriting in all files
require_once("db.php");

//If user Actually clicked register button
if(isset($_POST)) {

    //Escape Special Characters In String First
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
    //Encrypt Password
    $password = base64_encode(strrev(md5($password)));

    //sql query to check if email already exists or not
    $sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    //if email not found then we can insert new data
    if($result->num_rows == 0) {

            //This variable is used to catch errors doing upload process. False means there is some error and we need to notify that user.
    $uploadOk = true;

  // Code for image

  //Folder where you want to save your image. THIS FOLDER MUST BE CREATED BEFORE TRYING
$folder_dir = "uploads/logo/";

//Getting Basename of file. So if your file location is Documents/New Folder/myResume.pdf then base name will return myResume.pdf
$base = basename($_FILES['image']['name']); 

//This will get us extension of your file. So myimage.pdf will return pdf. If it was image.doc then this will return doc.
$imageFileType = pathinfo($base, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 

//Setting a random non repeatable file name. Uniqid will create a unique name based on current timestamp. We are using this because no two files can be of same name as it will overwrite.
$file = uniqid() . "." . $imageFileType; 

//This is where your files will be saved so in this case it will be uploads/image/newfilename
$filename = $folder_dir .$file;  

  if(file_exists($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) { 

            //Next we need to check if file type is of our allowed extention or not. I have only allowed pdf. You can allow doc, jpg etc. 
            if($imageFileType == "jpg" || $imageFileType == "png")  {

                //Next we need to check file size with our limit size. I have set the limit size to 5MB. Note if you set higher than 2MB then you must change your php.ini configuration and change upload_max_filesize and restart your server
                if($_FILES['image']['size'] < 500000) { // File size is less than 5MB

                    //If all above condition are met then copy file from server temp location to uploads folder.
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $filename);

                } else {
                    //Size Error
                    $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Wrong Size. Max Size Allowed : 5MB";
                    $uploadOk = false;
                }
            } else {
                //Format Error
                $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Wrong Format. Only jpg & png Allowed";
                $uploadOk = false;
            }
        } else {
                //File not copied to temp location error.
                $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Something Went Wrong. File Not Uploaded. Try Again.";
                $uploadOk = false;
            }

  // Code for resume

    //Folder where you want to save your resume. THIS FOLDER MUST BE CREATED BEFORE TRYING
    $folder_dir = "uploads/resume/";

    //Getting Basename of file. So if your file location is Documents/New Folder/myResume.pdf then base name will return myResume.pdf
    $base = basename($_FILES['resume']['name']); 

    //This will get us extension of your file. So myResume.pdf will return pdf. If it was resume.doc then this will return doc.
    $resumeFileType = pathinfo($base, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 

    //Setting a random non repeatable file name. Uniqid will create a unique name based on current timestamp. We are using this because no two files can be of same name as it will overwrite.
    $file = uniqid() . "." . $resumeFileType;   

    //This is where your files will be saved so in this case it will be uploads/resume/newfilename
    $filename = $folder_dir .$file;  

    //We check if file is saved to our temp location or not.
    if(file_exists($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'])) { 

        //Next we need to check if file type is of our allowed extention or not. I have only allowed pdf. You can allow doc, jpg etc. 
        if($resumeFileType == "pdf")  {

            //Next we need to check file size with our limit size. I have set the limit size to 5MB. Note if you set higher than 2MB then you must change your php.ini configuration and change upload_max_filesize and restart your server
            if($_FILES['resume']['size'] < 500000) { // File size is less than 5MB

                //If all above condition are met then copy file from server temp location to uploads folder.
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"], $filename);

            } else {
                //Size Error
                $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Wrong Size. Max Size Allowed : 5MB";
                $uploadOk = false;
            }
        } else {
            //Format Error
            $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Wrong Format. Only PDF Allowed";
            $uploadOk = false;
        }
    } else {
            //File not copied to temp location error.
            $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Something Went Wrong. File Not Uploaded. Try Again.";
            $uploadOk = false;
        }

    //If there is any error then redirect back.
    if($uploadOk == false) {
        header("Location: register-candidates.php");
        exit();
    }

        $hash = md5(uniqid());


        //sql new registration insert query
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users(email, password,resume, hash) VALUES ('$email', '$password','$file', '$hash')";

        if($conn->query($sql)===TRUE) {
            // Send Email

            // $to = $email;

            // $subject = "Job Portal - Confirm Your Email Address";

            // $message = '

            // <html>
            // <head>
            //  <title>Confirm Your Email</title>
            // <body>
            //  <p>Click Link To Confirm</p>
            //  <a href="yourdomain.com/verify.php?token='.$hash.'&email='.$email.'">Verify Email</a>
            // </body>
            // </html>
            // ';

            // $headers[] = 'MIME-VERSION: 1.0';
            // $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
            // $headers[] = 'To: '.$to;
            // $headers[] = 'From: hello@yourdomain.com';
            // //you add more headers like Cc, Bcc;

            // $result = mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers)); // \r\n will return new line. 

            // if($result === TRUE) {

            //  //If data inserted successfully then Set some session variables for easy reference and redirect to login
            //  $_SESSION['registerCompleted'] = true;
            //  header("Location: login.php");
            //  exit();

            // }

            // //If data inserted successfully then Set some session variables for easy reference and redirect to login
            $_SESSION['registerCompleted'] = true;
            header("Location: login.php");
            exit();
        } else {
            //If data failed to insert then show that error. Note: This condition should not come unless we as a developer make mistake or someone tries to hack their way in and mess up :D
            echo "Error " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    } else {
        //if email found in database then show email already exists error.
        $_SESSION['registerError'] = true;
        header("Location: candidateform.php");
        exit();
    }

    //Close database connection. Not compulsory but good practice.
    $conn->close();

} else {
    //redirect them back to register page if they didn't click register button
    header("Location: candidateform.php");
    exit();
}
```

Please note that this can be further shortened and is not the best programming IMHO.

Comment: thank you very much and thanks for the extra information. I'll surely try out this one.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have figured this out and not only that, I can upload different type of files without confusing them anymore. I hope my answer can be off help to another. Here it is;

adduser.php

```html
<?php

//To Handle Session Variables on This Page
session_start();

//Including Database Connection From db.php file to avoid rewriting in all files
require_once("db.php");

//If user Actually clicked register button
if(isset($_POST)) {
 $user_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['user_name']);
 $ic_no = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ic_no']);
 $nationality = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nationality']);
 $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['gender']);
 $race = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['race']);
 $ic_no = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ic_no']);
 $contactno = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['contactno']);
 $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
 $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['address']);
 $highest_qualification = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['highest_qualification']);
 $university = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['university']);
 $major = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['major']);
 $current_position = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['current_position']);
 $position_applied = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['position_applied']);
 $current_monthly_salary = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['current_monthly_salary']);
 $expected_monthly_salary = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['expected_monthly_salary']);
 $prefered_working_location = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['prefered_working_location']);
 $avaibility = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['avaibility']);
 $malay = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['malay']);
 $english = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['english']); 
 $mandarin = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['mandarin']);
 $other = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['other']);
 $aboutme = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['aboutme']);

    
 $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
 $password = base64_encode(strrev(md5($password)));

    //sql query to check if email already exists or not
    $sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    //if email not found then we can insert new data
    if($result->num_rows == 0) {

            //This variable is used to catch errors doing upload process. False means there is some error and we need to notify that user.
    $uploadOk = true;



 // Code for image
$folder_dir = "uploads/logo/";
$base = basename($_FILES['image']['name']); 
$imageFileType = pathinfo($base, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
$file = uniqid() . "." . $imageFileType; 
$filename = $folder_dir .$file;  

  if(file_exists($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) { 

            if($imageFileType == "jpg" || $imageFileType == "png")  {

                if($_FILES['image']['size'] < 500000) { // File size is less than 5MB

                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $filename);

                } else {
                 
                    $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Wrong Size. Max Size Allowed : 5MB";
                    $uploadOk = false;
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Wrong Format. Only jpg & png Allowed";
                $uploadOk = false;
            }
        } else {
                $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Something Went Wrong. File Not Uploaded. Try Again.";
                $uploadOk = false;
            }

  // Code for resume

 
    $folder_dir = "uploads/resume/";
    $base = basename($_FILES['resume']['name']); 
    $resumeFileType = pathinfo($base, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
    $file1 = uniqid() . "." . $resumeFileType;   
    $filename = $folder_dir .$file1;  
    if(file_exists($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'])) { 

        if($resumeFileType == "pdf"|| $resumeFileType == "doc")  {
            if($_FILES['resume']['size'] < 500000) { 
   
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"], $filename);

            } else {
              
                $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Wrong Size. Max Size Allowed : 5MB";
                $uploadOk = false;
            }
        } else {
        
            $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Wrong Format. Only PDF Allowed";
            $uploadOk = false;
        }
    } else {
            //File not copied to temp location error.
            $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Something Went Wrong. File Not Uploaded. Try Again.";
            $uploadOk = false;
        }

    //If there is any error then redirect back.
    if($uploadOk == false) {
        header("Location: register-candidates.php");
        exit();
    }

        $hash = md5(uniqid());


        //sql new registration insert query
  $sql="INSERT INTO users (user_name, ic_no, gender, email, password, address, nationality, contactno, highest_qualification, university, major, current_position,
  position_applied, current_monthly_salary, expected_monthly_salary, prefered_working_location, avaibility, malay, english, mandarin, other, logo, resume, hash, aboutme) VALUES
  ('$user_name', '$ic_no', '$gender', '$email', '$password', '$address', '$nationality', '$contactno', '$highest_qualification', '$university', '$major', '$current_position',
  '$position_applied', '$current_monthly_salary', '$expected_monthly_salary', '$prefered_working_location', '$avaibility', '$malay', '$english', '$mandarin',
  '$other', '$file', '$file1', '$hash', '$aboutme')";
  
  
  
        if($conn->query($sql)===TRUE) {
            // Send Email

            // $to = $email;

            // $subject = "Job Portal - Confirm Your Email Address";

            // $message = '

            // <html>
            // <head>
            //  <title>Confirm Your Email</title>
            // <body>
            //  <p>Click Link To Confirm</p>
            //  <a href="yourdomain.com/verify.php?token='.$hash.'&email='.$email.'">Verify Email</a>
            // </body>
            // </html>
            // ';

            // $headers[] = 'MIME-VERSION: 1.0';
            // $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
            // $headers[] = 'To: '.$to;
            // $headers[] = 'From: hello@yourdomain.com';
            // //you add more headers like Cc, Bcc;

            // $result = mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers)); // \r\n will return new line. 

            // if($result === TRUE) {

            //  //If data inserted successfully then Set some session variables for easy reference and redirect to login
            //  $_SESSION['registerCompleted'] = true;
            //  header("Location: login.php");
            //  exit();

            // }

            // //If data inserted successfully then Set some session variables for easy reference and redirect to login
            $_SESSION['registerCompleted'] = true;
            header("Location: login-candidates.php");
            exit();
        } else {
            //If data failed to insert then show that error. Note: This condition should not come unless we as a developer make mistake or someone tries to hack their way in and mess up :D
            echo "Error " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    } else {
        //if email found in database then show email already exists error.
        $_SESSION['registerError'] = true;
        header("Location: candidate-register.php");
        exit();
    }

    //Close database connection. Not compulsory but good practice.
    $conn->close();

} else {
    //redirect them back to register page if they didn't click register button
    header("Location: candidate-register.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```